# VPN connection to Amazon RDS with openvpn suddenly fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, openvpn

I set `AWS Client VPN Endpoint`, and downloaded opvn file, configured it to refer to cert/key files and connected to AWS RDS.

It used to success connecting yesterday, but today, after re-installing ESET security app

It shows the following error when I trying connecting with MySQL client app:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'myrds.something.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (0)
```

I am not sure how to detect the cause of the error. If I configured RDS settings to pubilc, the error above not shown and just waiting for minutes...

(maybe I guess some DNS settings overriden by ESET? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily debug the problem:

1. AWS Client VPN Endpoint, You can see the active connection. See if you are connected to it or not.
2. Do you restarted or reinstall RDS also, Because it will change the URL to connect.
3. Is username/password of DB is changed.
4. If RDS is in public setting you don't even need a VPN connection.
5. Also as suggested above check VPN to RDS VPC Route.

Thanks,

AB

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Somehow now the vpn is safely connected and probably it was because temporarily my DNS table? (cache?) has been contaminated.

Answer (score 1):

here are some troubleshooting steps.

When you connect your VPN:

- Check if it's pushing the DNS server address via DHCP configuration
- Check if new routes are added to your route table. you can do "route print" in the windows command line

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, now I can connect